# query key from complex json by combining dict2items and JMESPath with ansible

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x, jmespath

I'm looking to return value based on query result,  so far I'm not getting the desired result.
json looks like this and is coming from ansible var

```
{
  "header": {
    "nodes": {
        "node1": {
            "last_shutdown": "date",
            "level": {
                "kind_node": {}
            },
            "state": {
                "running": "true",
                "more": {
                    "type": "admin"
            }
        }
    },
        "node2": {
            "last_shutdown": "date",
            "level": {
                "kind_node": {}
            },
            "state": {
                "running": "true",
                "more": {
                    "type": "engine"
            }
        }
    },
        "node3": {
            "last_shutdown": "date",
            "level": {
                "kind_node": {}
            },
            "state": {
                "running": "true",
                "more": {
                    "type": "engine"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far I've tried to use dict2items but no luck. Currently, I'm getting an empty list.

```
     set_fact:
       my_var: "{{ nodes | dict2items | json_query('[?value.state.more.type==`admin`]') }}"
```

Basically, this task should set my_var ==> node1 since it's the admin. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `json_query` for this. It would work but I strongly suggest you use it only when default core ansible filters cannot do the job at all.

Moreover, your `jmespath` expression (which I did not test to validate) would return a full list of elements where the parameter is matched, not simply a node name.

In a nutshell (note: updated so that it will work even if some element do not contain the `more` attribute inside the `state` key)

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_var: >-
      {{
        nodes 
        | dict2items
        | selectattr('value.state.more', 'defined')
        | selectattr('value.state.more.type', '==', 'admin')
        | map(attribute='key')
        | first
      }}
```

In other words:

1. transform dict to a list or `key`/`value` pairs
2. select only elements having `value.state.more` defined
3. select only elements having `"admin"` in the `value.state.more.type` parameter
4. extract only the `key` parameter for each element
5. get the first element in the list

Comment: I got the following error, ```"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'more'". by the way I've updated the json right before you responded.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/b9479f40b41814af8d963f68138fcc0a

Comment: The above error was encountered if element tree doe not contain `more`. Otherwise the provided solution works.

Comment: This is not a situation you have described. You have to be specific by providing a relevant data set. I updated the solution so that it will work in this case.

Comment: correct, I missed that use case. I was able to filter some more and handle other cases with your updated solution. Appreciate your help on this. all set.